# Substitute xhtml default css file

Tags: python, python-2.7, xhtml2pdf

I have my own css file and I would like to use it instead of what xhtml2pdf has by default. The documentation says:

xhtml2pdf --css-dump > xhtml2pdf-default.css

Creates that file and allows me to change it but how could I do this in windows?

Comment: what is `xhtml2pdf` ? what `windows` do you mean ? Mabey you need `os.system("xhtml2pdf --css-dump > xhtml2pdf-default.css")` to run it in Python ?

Comment: Hello, xhtml2pdf is a library to create PDF files from a source html. And what did the trick was to run the executable file from the library.